# Facebook channelURL file with PyroCMS

Tags: file, .htaccess, pyrocms

Im using PyroCMS and Im trying to upload some static pages that I DO NOT wan the CMS to know about.

On my server I have a folder named "static"

mydomain.com/static

When I navigate to it PyroDisplays the 404 page. so far ok as I dont have a page named static in the pages Module.

In my Facebook script I need to point the channelURL  to a PHP file to mydomain.com/static/channel.php
**channel.php**

```
 <?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

**Output**

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php:1) in /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php:1) in /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php on line 4

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php:1) in /home2/inspire1/public_html/static/channel.php on line 5
```

So my question is how to I implement the `channel.php` file alongside PyroCMS.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this.

PyroCMS (well, Apache) will not try to send any URL to index.php (our front controller) if the file in the URL is a valid file or directory.

So when you hit `/static` its going to use and `/static.php` is going to your file. Thems the rules.

The second problem looks like you have unexpected whitespace in your PHP file before the initial `<?php` tag. Make sure there are no spaces or empty lines up there.